# Will rooting my Samsung Galaxy S before I activate it cause any problems?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, rooting, samsung-fascinate

I have a samsung Galaxy S (Fascinate) that I haven't decided if I want to keep, so I haven't activated it on my Verizon account. I'd like to root it and flash a new ROM (possibly a separate Kernel) but I'm wondering if doing so when it is not connected to any carrier will cause any problems, particularly with the voice/data connection settings?

Comment: You mean activate it with the carrier right? I don't think rooting will matter, as far as I know it's just linking the ESN to Verzion.

Comment: Yes, activing it on vzw.  The only reason I paused was the concern that certain relating to the apn or other carrier specific connection settings might get messed up if I rooted and flashed a new ROM when it wasn't activated on the carrier.  I forgot to mention the flashing of the ROM.  Is it just linking the ESN? I thought the provisioning process involved setting all the connection settings as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt it.  I've done the same with a GSM Galaxy S (the Vibrant) with no problems.  Of course it probably depends on whether you have a really terrible ROM, but rooting alone shouldn't matter.  And it might be different for CDMA.  But worst case, you can just flash back to stock.  My Vibrant picked up the network settings on it's first boot with a SIM, I would again assume your first boot-up after activation would cause the same thing.  Plus, if the custom ROM is Captivate-based and not i9000-based, it might have the network settings already built in (and just need to pick up the phone number).

Comment: Sounds good, that's what I figured.  It was actually your question about your connection settings getting messed up after switching the SIM that freaked me out a little because on CDMA the closest thing we have to switching SIMs is going through the carriers provisioning.  I'll accept this from my Fascinate after I root and access the 3G with no problem.

Comment: Yeah I figured that might be the case.  I'll try to figure out which app not to restore data for ... but with a new device you presumably have no backup data to restore.

Comment: Ugh. I just activated and now it says I have no APNs configured.

Comment: Hmm I just found this app, would have been useful before: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.riteshsahu.APNBackupRestore.  But at least that means you can edit the APN.  Just a matter of finding the right settings ... and there's always the option of a factory reset.

Comment: haha, yes, this would have been helpful before.  I already did the factory reset and everything working now.  So rooting before activation won't cause any problems, but flashing a new ROM may?  That's what it seems like but I don't really feel like testing this further now that I have it working.

Comment: I extracted the `/system/etc/apns-conf.xml` file from stock EB01: http://www.eng.uwaterloo.ca/~mread/apns-conf.xml **Edit:** Ah, good to hear.  Now we know, I guess :P

Comment: Thanks for the APN config file, that may come in handy some day.

Comment: The more I think about this, flashing a new ROM shouldn't have been a problem.  The Fascinate is only available on VZW so you'd think that any ROM compiled for that phone would have all the necessary settings as well.  Do you think it was just a fluke that my APN settings didn't take (specific to that ROM) or do you think this is a broader issue with custom ROMs?  I imagine most people activate their phones first so this may not come up much.

Comment: That was my thought exactly, custom ROMs should still have the right APN and everything.  I do see other people activating after flashig on XDA though, I wonder if this is relevant: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=11619311&postcount=559

Answer (score 0):

You will not get voice/data if it is not activated on your VZW account. But you can use it as a wifi device, like an iPod. I say root it and flash an ICS ROM to see what the device can do. I think you'll be surprised! Go [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1238070) for all the info you need to root/flash/return it to stock if you decide to sell it.