# Can a Sprint-branded Samsung Intercept be flashed to Virgin Mobile?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, carriers, samsung-intercept

I am getting a Sprint-branded Samsung Intercept that was rooted and flashed to MetroPCS and runs Froyo. Can I flash it to Virgin Mobile?

Answer (score 2):

If you unlock the phone (as presumably you did to get it on Metro PCS), you should be able to flash the Virgin ROM and activate it on Virgin.  However, you should call Virgin and ask!  They can best answer this question, and you'll need them to activate the phone on their network anyways.

Comment: if the phone is already rooted to go from sprint to pcs metro which we dont have here-where do i get the virgin mobile rom-do i just change the baseband file only, do i try to make it stock sprint then try to swap that for stock virgin so i can get their update froyo or what

Comment: You should definitely flash the whole Virgin ROM, not just the baseband.  In fact I wouldn't be surprised if the baseband is the same.  It's more about the APN configuration and that sort of thing.  One of the mods had a related question, our comments on my answer to it might be of some use: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/will-rooting-my-samsung-galaxy-s-before-i-activate-it-cause-any-problems